# VBA array formula to get description where score between two values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

I have the following cells of score ranges and descriptions:

```
Statement  Critical  Significant Average  Minor Non-critical
Grades     0.8       0.6         0.4      0.2   0
```

I have a data-set where grades will range from 0 to 1 and would like to create a string variable for each observation that will print the above statements based on the grades.

So, for a random cell `X1` my formula is:

```
={IF(X1>=A2:A6;B2:B6)}
```

But this array formula returns `False` if the value is 0.3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a standard combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH` to solve this problem. The formula would be (per screenshot below):

`=INDEX($F$2:$J$2,MATCH(B8,$F$3:$J$3,-1))`

Where

- `$F$2:$J$2`- the list of 'statements' e.g. critical, significant
- `B8` - the grade in question
- `$F$3:$J$3` - the range of grade ranges
- `-1` - as an argument to the `MATCH` function is 'greater than'

Screenshot:

[image]

In that example, note that a score where `0.4 < score <= 0.6` gives `Significant`. However you might want that range to return `Average` in which case the whole `MATCH` function needs an offset e.g.:

`=INDEX($F$2:$J$2,MATCH(B8,$F$3:$J$3,-1)+1)`

But note for a grade of `0` this will give a `#REF!` error unless you create a new 'statement' e.g. 'less than critical' with a score of -1.

Also, note that your array formula:

`={IF(X1>=A2:A6;B2:B6)}`

Is not quite right - normally you enter a formula and then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to create an array formula which in your case would be like this:

`{=IF(X1>=A2:A6;B2:B6)}`

But that doesn't work for me - I think it is easier for you to just the `INDEX` and `MATCH` approach unless you absolutely need an array formula.